# SWIG + Go: C source files not allowed when not using cgo

Tags: go, build, swig

I am trying to wrap this library (https://github.com/lemire/EWAHBoolArray) in Go using SWIG, but I'm having a lot of problems since I upgraded to 1.4

I had successfully gotten everything to work using Go 1.3.3 and following the instructions on the SWIG site for SWIG + Go. I had to compile and install the package manually instead of using go build, but everything was working fine.

Now, when I try to run the same program with Go 1.4.2, I get this error:

```
ewah_usage.go:5:2: C source files not allowed when not using cgo: goewah_gc.c
```

I rebuilt the package using the latest SWIG and the latest Go, and it seems to have installed correctly. But whenever I run a program using the library, I get the above error.

My test program (goewah is the library I built with SWIG)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bitbucket.org/evanh/goewah"
)

func main() {
    x := goewah.NewEWAHBoolArray()
    x.Set(1)
    x.Set(2)
    fmt.Println(x.Get(1))
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like you're using swig if you're getting this error and I can't see the code since it's a private repo.

Comment: Presumably the way you're building your program has disabled Go.  Without seeing what command you ran, it is difficult to say exactly why.  Assuming you didn't set `CGO_ENABLED=0`, the other possibility is if you tried to cross compile the program, which disables it by default.

Comment: I've moved the code to a public repo. The Makefile is terrible, I know. The current one works with Mac OS X, and I have another one that works with Linux. The Makefile currently uses a hardcoded GOPATH and GOROOT.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a bug.  Sorry.  Add a file that just says

```
package p
import "C"
```

and you should get around it.

Comment: I added a new package exactly as you said, but it didn't fix anything. I still get the same error.

Comment: Not a new package, a new .go file in the same package.

Comment: Ah I see. That fixed the error. Now I get a bunch of SWIG errors. Still, forward progress! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While adding CGO_ENABLED=0 to commands like `go test` can work,
the editor still keeps warning at top of go files all the time.

Just add to top of your C/C++ source files, like:

```c
//go:build ignore
```

Links:
- https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Build_constraints
- https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/566878192
- https://github.com/fritx/mixed-playground/blob/main/strings/2129.%20%E5%B0%86%E6%A0%87%E9%A2%98%E9%A6%96%E5%AD%97%E6%AF%8D%E5%A4%A7%E5%86%99.cc